# Difference between constructors in dart class

Tags: dart

```
class Product {
  Product(this.name);

  final String name;
}

class Product {
  Product({this.name});

  final String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the parameter is mandatory positional (you still can pass `null` though).
You can call it like:

```
new Product('Fred')
```

In the 2nd example the parameter is an optional named parameter.
You can call it like:

```
new Product()
new Product(name: 'Fred')
```

Another variant would be an optional positional parameter

```
class Product {
  Product([this.name]);

  final String name;
}
```

You can call it like:

```
new Product()
new Product('Fred')
```

Optional parameter always need to be declared after mandatory parameters.
Optional named and optional positional can not be combined.

Answer (score 0):

The `{ }` in the `constructor` are used to make the constructor arguments optional.

```
class Product {
   Product(this.name);
   final String name;
  }
```

In the above code notice, there are no `{ }` around arguments in constructor hence while creating a new object using the `Product` class it's mandatory to provide `name`

```
class Product {
  Product({this.name});
  final String name;
 }
```

While in the above code the `name` argument is optional as it has `{ }` around it. So while creating an object using this class you can skip the `name` parameter.